# UICollectionView into UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

I have a problem when I try to use a CollectionView into UIView.

This is the code example of my view.

```
class CampanasView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

class func create() -> CampanasView {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CampanasView", bundle: nil)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as? CampanasView

    //if you use xibs:
    view?.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CampanaCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CampanaCell")
    view?.collectionView.reloadData()
    return view!
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CampanaCell", for: indexPath) as! CampanaCell


    return cell
}

}
```

This is the xib

[image: Xib File of the UIView]

In my ViewController I have this code to add UIView into ViewController

```
var campanasView: CampanasView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.campanasView = CampanasView.create()
    _ = JAutolayouts.fillContainer(self.contentView, view: self.campanasView!)
}
```

This is the error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[WinUp.CampanasView collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10beac100'

Comment: can you post how is your setup for your CampanasView xib file?

Comment: Also, who calls your create() and when?

Comment: try this: add in viewDidLoad method collectionView.DataSource = self

Comment: @Smartcat the method create() I use when instance the view into ViewController

Comment: Yes I set a datasource and delegate into de xib @user1000

Comment: set in ViewDidLoad method too

Comment: using collectionView in containerView ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is related to the setup of your xib, you need unlink your collection view delegate and datasource from your fileOwner and add this two lines in your `create` method

```
    view?.collectionView.dataSource = view
    view?.collectionView.delegate = view
```

And as I said above you need unlink datasource and delegate of your CollectionView

[image]

**your `create` method must be like this**

```
class func create() -> CampanasView {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CampanasView", bundle: nil)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as? CampanasView

        //if you use xibs:
        view?.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CampanaCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CampanaCell")
        view?.collectionView.dataSource = view
        view?.collectionView.delegate = view
        view?.collectionView.reloadData()
        return view!
    }
```